# Switch the order in semPaths graph

Tags: r, structural-equation-model, semplot

I'm using lavaan for my sem model and I'm having troubles in representing the final path-diagram. Basically, I would like to have the mediating variable (ability) in the middle of the graph i.e switching the position with education. For a better understanding I attach the obtained graph and the related code:

```
new_order<- ' 
#Measurement model - latent variables  
ability =~ c_cgwri_dv + c_cgwrd_dv + c_cgs7ca_dv + c_cgvfc_dv + c_cgna_dv
education=~edu_r 
income=~log_income 
father_class=~a_panssec8_dv 
agree =~ c_big5a_dv 
consc =~ c_big5c_dv
neur =~ c_big5n_dv 
open =~ c_big5o_dv 
extro =~ c_big5e_dv 
employment =~ job_type
experience =~ labour_experience

#Structural model - Pahts 
education ~ father_class + agree + neur + open + extro + consc 
ability ~ education + father_class 
income ~ education + ability + father_class + agree + neur + open + extro + consc + employment +  experience 


#Correlations
c_cgwri_dv ~~ c_cgwrd_dv
c_cgs7ca_dv ~~ c_cgna_dv
c_cgwri_dv ~~ c_cgvfc_dv
c_cgwrd_dv ~~ c_cgvfc_dv
c_cgvfc_dv ~~ c_cgna_dv
c_cgs7ca_dv ~~ c_cgvfc_dv
employment ~~ ability 
employment ~~ education 
experience ~~ ability 
education ~~ experience 
agree ~~ ability 
consc ~~ ability 
neur ~~ ability 
open ~~ ability 
extro ~~ ability
father_class ~~ agree + consc + neur + open + extro

'

order_fit<-sem(new_order, male, missing="ml", sampling.weights = "c_indscub_xw")
summary(order_fit, standardize=T, fit.measures=T, rsq=T)

semPaths(order_fit, what="std", fade=F, edge.label.cex=1, sizeMan=7, sizeLat=7, exoCov = F, exoVar = F, intercepts = F, rotation = 2)
```

[image]

Any idea on how can I switch the position of ability (abl) and education (edc)? 
Thanks

Comment: ?semPath, try looking at `reorder=FALSE`

Comment: In addition, try looking at lavaanPlot https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaanPlot/vignettes/Intro_to_lavaanPlot.html

Comment: @DJV yep, I tried reorder=F, but the result is exactly the same. I will have a look at lavaanPlot, thanks for the link!